# controlling Embedded system from MOBILE. ANDROID or iOS? suggestions and explanations please

Tags: android, iphone, ios, pic, avr

As a part of feasibly study. I need to choose between Android or iOS for integrating it with an embedded system.

Basically, that embedded system will have an AVR or a PIC Microcontroller. I want to establish a communication between a mobile and that particular system.

Need some wireless technology for communication (bluetooth,wifi,internet etc..)
Micro Controllers have communication ports like UART, USART etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the kind of communication you need.

I particular, if you have a normal WIFI connection and your controller can work with receiving & sending your data via wifi, you may go iOS or Android.

If however you need some kind of free format serial communication, you need to go Android, serial cable via USB.

recarding other factors, I guess it really is just a personal taste issue.

Could you give more info on how & what needs to be communicated and what kind of communication device you have between your phone and the device itself.

Not sure if this is similar to what you have in minde, but you might look at this: http://www.arduino.cc/ being probably the best known example in this context.

Comment: Lets say am going to use serial communication. I basically want to establish a communication between a mobile and a embedded system, perhaps bitwise (means, if I generate a byte like 00100100 in the transmitter either mobile or in that controller and vise versa).

I want my mobile also to send a byte code, or at least an ANSCII code. 
this is what i am having in mind.
want to establish a communication OF ANY SORT. (if what i said above is not possible)

Comment: again, it really depends what kind of communication adapter your device can use. if all it can do is serial, then you will need USB Android cable, if it can do BT or WIFI you are free to use whatever you like. please tell more about the communication interface, so i can help more...

Comment: Bluetooth is better. And what i need is.
when i touchup a button in my iphone(or android). an LED glows. very simple. i can do all ui in iOS but i hav no idea about the communication

Comment: so if your device can connect via BT then you may just use Android, since its BT communication very well documented and supported. Check http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html or any other BT tutorial - works really well!

Answer (score 1):

Using some serial to bluetooth module would be the most easier to implement.

Comment: ya but how. what responds to the modules better. iOS or Android.

Comment: Android, of course! :) - Apple chooses to implement 'standards' their own way so that I would expect some trouble when trying to use their Bluetooth with a Non-Apple device. On the embedded side there are several Bluetooth modules available for less than US$ 10, for instance the CSR BC-05.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Android unless your target audience are photographers.  Seriously.  Also, with iOS you need to be careful.  For instance you want to use BlueTooth, but not all iOS devices will connect to, say, the Bluetooth protocol for a keyboard.  (Ah! You didn't know there were more then one Bluetooth protocol did you?)  And I don't think any iOS device will let you connect using the Bluetooth serial port protocol.

With Android you can jump in and start flying immediately by using the (or a copy of) the PIC 24F based IOIO board.  And if you are an Android / Eclipse developer (I think) you can down load and use the IOIO JAVA / Android libraries.  I have been told this makes programming the IOIO board just about as easy as programming an Arduino.  Especially if you are well versed in JAVA, Android and the Eclipse editor.  Add to this the IOIO board can be a host to the Android (i.e. connected by wired USB) or host to some Bluetooth modules (i.e. connect to the Andoid's bluetooth radio).

If you don't want to go it along you can buy the Microchip Android Development Kit (ADK) board which is also a PIC 24F based "USB wired" using AOA protocol to connect to an Android.  I say "not going it alone" as I would expect you can then get limited support from Microchip w.r.t. their hardware (the ADK board), software (Android) and firmware (PIC ADk board).  This solution, however, does not have built in Bluetooth support.  I am guessing you can add it, it's just not part of the ADK software/firmware that Microchip put together.